# How to fetch and validate xml content in log file in Python?

Tags: xml, logging

I need to parse some log files in which contents are XML like, but it doesnt have a root and has text contents in between.

Log file format is:

```
2019-09-12 15:30:02.137 (162,<ThreadPool>    ) Info          Sending:
<Keepalive />
2019-09-12 15:30:03.512 (65 ,Estate            ) DebugInfo     Incoming buffer has 292 bytes
<Outcome>
  <ItemId>373011</ItemId>
  <AreaId>232</AreaId>
  <CarrierId>131</CarrierId>
  <AResult>
    <Measured>Ok</Measured>
  </AResult>
    <TimeStamp>2019-09-12T19:30:02Z</TimeStamp>
</Outcome>

2019-09-12 15:32:02.137 (162,<ThreadPool>    ) Info          Sending:
<Keepalive />
2019-09-12 15:32:03.512 (65 ,Estate            ) DebugInfo     Incoming buffer has 292 bytes
<Outcome>
  <ItemId>373012</ItemId>
  <AreaId>232</AreaId>
  <CarrierId>131</CarrierId>
  <AResult>
    <Measured>Ok</Measured>
  </AResult>
    <TimeStamp>2019-09-12T19:32:02Z</TimeStamp>
</Outcome>
```

Since it is a log file Can I use ElementTree library for this? I need to validate Measured OK for different item ID.

I tried these , none of them worked:
(1)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
with open('C:\lovely\Libraries\site.log') as f:
xml = f.read()
tree = ET.fromstring(re.sub(r"(<\?xml[^>]+\?>)", r"\1<root>", xml) + "</root>")
```

Comment: What are you trying to extract from the log file?

Comment: @Jack Fleeting I need to validate if <Measured> is 'OK' for different ItemID

Comment: Can you use lxml instead of ET? It's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not going to be possible to parse a file contain random snippets of text and XML mixed in together. The text parts are very likely to contain things that are XML-like but not well-formed (like `<\?xml[^>]+\?>`); distinguishing that from XML is impossible in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It has high fault tolerance and treats data as text.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
2019-09-12 15:30:02.137 (162,<ThreadPool>    ) Info          Sending:
<Keepalive />
2019-09-12 15:30:03.512 (65 ,Estate            ) DebugInfo     Incoming buffer has 292 bytes
<Outcome>
  <ItemId>373011</ItemId>
  <AreaId>232</AreaId>
  <CarrierId>131</CarrierId>
  <AResult>
    <Measured>Ok</Measured>
  </AResult>
    <TimeStamp>2019-09-12T19:30:02Z</TimeStamp>
</Outcome>

2019-09-12 15:32:02.137 (162,<ThreadPool>    ) Info          Sending:
<Keepalive />
2019-09-12 15:32:03.512 (65 ,Estate            ) DebugInfo     Incoming buffer has 292 bytes
<Outcome>
  <ItemId>373012</ItemId>
  <AreaId>232</AreaId>
  <CarrierId>131</CarrierId>
  <AResult>
    <Measured>Ok</Measured>
  </AResult>
    <TimeStamp>2019-09-12T19:32:02Z</TimeStamp>
</Outcome>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# Outcome = doc.Outcome
Outcomes = doc.Outcomes 
print(Outcomes.ItemId.text, Outcomes.AreaId.text)
```

Result:

```
['373011', '373012'] ['232', '232']
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: That looks helpful if I have only 1 set of 'Outcome'. But since it is a log file there are other Outcome messages with different ItemId's coming through, simplified doc doesnt go look for the whole document I think? It always gives me the first Item Id only

Comment: I dont understand what change it introduce once you change outcome to 'outcomes', any mistake?

Comment: @LLovely Adding the end of s means taking all.

Comment: Not sure if I understand that. I have updated log with its 2nd Outcome message. It only prints 373011, and not picking ItemId 373012

Comment: @LLovely I don't know what's wrong with you. I paste your whole log in and it prints out two records.